# How can I get the vertices of all cells in a container with Voro++ Library?

Tags: c++, 3d, voronoi

I try to implement a simple 3d voronoi application with Voro++. I have a container containing particles. After putting all the particles in the container, how can I get the vertices of all voronoicells computed by Voro++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the documentation it should be something like this:
http://math.lbl.gov/voro++/examples/polygons/

the doc says:
On line 47, a call is made to the face_vertices routine, which returns information about which vertices comprise each face. It is a vector of integers with a specific format: the first entry is a number k corresponding to the number of vertices making up a face, and this is followed k additional entries describing which vertices make up this face. For example, the sequence (3, 16, 20, 13) would correspond to a triangular face linking vertices 16, 20, and 13 together. On line 48, the vertex positions are returned: this corresponds to a vector of triplets (x, y, z) describing the position of each vertex.

i modified the example script so that it stores every particles cell connections and vertex positions in vectors. but please verify this!
hope this helps!

```
#include "voro++.hh"
#include "container.hh"
#include <v_compute.hh>
#include <c_loops.hh>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

 using namespace voro;

int main() {

    // Set up constants for the container geometry
    const double x_min=-5,x_max=5;
    const double y_min=-5,y_max=5;
    const double z_min=0,z_max=10;

    unsigned int i,j;
    int id,nx,ny,nz;
    double x,y,z;
    std::vector<int> neigh;
    voronoicell_neighbor c;

    // Set up the number of blocks that the container is divided into
    const int n_x=6,n_y=6,n_z=6;

    // Create a container with the geometry given above, and make it
    // non-periodic in each of the three coordinates. Allocate space for
    // eight particles within each computational block
    container con(x_min,x_max,y_min,y_max,z_min,z_max,n_x,n_y,n_z,
                 false,false,false,8);

    //Randomly add particles into the container
    con.import("pack_six_cube");

    // Save the Voronoi network of all the particles to text files
    // in gnuplot and POV-Ray formats
    con.draw_cells_gnuplot("pack_ten_cube.gnu");
    con.draw_cells_pov("pack_ten_cube_v.pov");

    // Output the particles in POV-Ray format
    con.draw_particles_pov("pack_ten_cube_p.pov");

    // Loop over all particles in the container and compute each Voronoi
    // cell
    c_loop_all cl(con);
    int dimension = 0;
    if(cl.start()) do if(con.compute_cell(c,cl)) {
        dimension+=1;
    } while (cl.inc());

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > face_connections(dimension);
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vertex_positions(dimension);

    int counter = 0;

    if(cl.start()) do if(con.compute_cell(c,cl)) {
        cl.pos(x,y,z);id=cl.pid();

        std::vector<int> f_vert;
        std::vector<double> v;

        // Gather information about the computed Voronoi cell
        c.neighbors(neigh);

        c.face_vertices(f_vert);
        c.vertices(x,y,z,v);

        face_connections[counter] = f_vert;
        vertex_positions[counter] = v;

        std::cout << f_vert.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;

        counter += 1;
      } while (cl.inc());


}
```

Regards, Lukas

Comment: So, how can I store this values in a vector or array?